# Show random (old & new) videos from YouTube subscriptions

Tags: web-apps, chrome, web, youtube, browser-extension

I'm looking for a chrome extension or something similar that enables me to explore random videos from my subscriptions.

I'm well aware of "https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions", but it only shows the latest videos of my subscriptions. I want a page similar to how YouTube home page used to look years ago showing mainly random old and new videos from the list of subscriptions.

Bonus point it shouldn't list a video that I disliked or watched before.